# Suggested edit made by unprivileged editor not shown to editor in Review Queues

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

When reviewing first questions or answers sometimes there's a edit that is necessary.

When you don't have enough reputation your edit gets reviewed, but there's a message that you can see your edit; and indeed that's **usually** true  except when you go back to the review queue.

When you are back reviewing you get the message that you can see the edit that you suggested, but that's not true; the revised version isn't shown to the unprivileged editor.

Review Queue: https://ai.stackexchange.com/review/first-answers/26140

> [image]

Notice that the banner is incorrect, the revised version isn't shown.

Submitted edit: [ChatGPT $20/month vs. ChatGPT API](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/41035/chatgpt-20-month-vs-chatgpt-api/41041#41041)

> [image]

See, it's correct, outside of the Review Queues.